# Collapsing a vertical Bootstrap navbar for mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Bootstrap 5.3 and trying to figure out how to collapse this sidebar behind a hamburger menu below medium size. I've tried various things using the built-in classes and utilities, but they are all designed to work with a horizontal navbar. So adding them works up to a point, but then everything goes sideways (literally.)

```html
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container py-2">
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light shadow-sm p-0" id="topnav">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="m-0 text-uppercase">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        Hello World
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main class="container py-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 py-md-1 px-md-0 me-md-2 bg-body shadow border-1">
                    <div class="row p-3 d-none d-md-flex">
                        <div class="col mr align-self-center">
                            Notice
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="leftnav">
                        <a class="nav-link d-flex" href="#">Menu 1</a>
                        <a class="nav-link d-flex" href="#">Menu 2</a>
                        <a class="nav-link d-flex active" href="#">Menu 3</a>
                        <a class="nav-link d-flex" href="#">Menu 4</a>
                        <a class="nav-link d-flex" href="#">Menu 5</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 py-md-1 ms-md-2 bg-body justify-content-center shadow-sm">
                    Here's where the content goes.
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

This HTML was developed years ago for Bootstrap 3 or 4, and has been gradually patched up to work with modern versions. I'm open to rethinking the whole structure (I'm already considering just moving to a Bootstrap-approved horizontal navbar to save the trouble.) I do not want to have two copies of my sidebar, which is an approach I've seen recommended in the few non-ancient posts I could find on collapsing sidebars.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did end up reworking the layout considerably. Support for vertical navbars was removed in Bootstrap 5.1 (?) because they introduced the [offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/offcanvas/) component so I used that and scrapped the row/col grid on the outermost elements. Posting an answer in case it helps anyone in the future.

```css
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    div#app .shadow-sm {
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light shadow-sm p-md-0 bg-transparent" id="topnav">
            <div class="container justify-content-start">
                <button class="navbar-toggler me-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#leftnav" aria-controls="leftnav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <h1 class="m-0 text-uppercase">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        Hello World
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 py-md-4">
            <nav id="leftnav" class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 offcanvas-md offcanvas-start py-md-1 px-md-0 me-md-2 bg-body shadow-sm">
                <div class="offcanvas-header">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#leftnav" aria-controls="leftnav" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="nav offcanvas-body nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                    <div class="row p-3 pt-0 d-none d-md-flex">
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-1 align-self-center">
                            Notice
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="nav-link d-flex" href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <a class="nav-link d-flex" href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    <a class="nav-link d-flex active" href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <a class="nav-link d-flex" href="#">Menu 4</a>
                    <a class="nav-link d-flex" href="#">Menu 5</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="flex-fill py-md-1 ms-md-2 bg-body justify-content-center shadow-sm">
                <div class="container">
                    Here's where the content goes.
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body></html>
```